# Updating existing table row by pulling data into form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working a project where I can add 'Actors' to a table via Form input, that allows me to click on a table row and pull the data of the selected Actor back into the form for update/delete. I'm able to select the data, and delete the row, but I cannot figure out how to update an existing row. I can't seem to find anything to help link new input to existing object data.

******* Updated *********

```
var actors = [];


var selectActor = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var rowClicked = $(this).parent().parent();
    row = rowClicked.index();
    alert(actors[row].fName + " " + actors[row].lName + " " + actors[row].gender + " " + actors[row].birthDate + " " + actors[row].action + " " + actors[row].comedy + " " + actors[row].drama + " " + actors[row].suspense + " " + actors[row].sciencefiction + " " + actors[row].horror);
    console.log(actors[row]);
    var idx = $(this).attr("data-idx");
    var actor = actors[idx];
    $("#updateActor").attr("rowid",idx);
    for (var key in actor) {
        var ele = $("#" + fieldTypes[key].id);
        var type = fieldTypes[key].type;
        switch (type) {
            case "input":
                ele.val(actor[key]);
                break;
            case "radio":
                var name = fieldTypes[key].name;
                $("[name='" + name + "']").prop({ checked:false });
                $("[name='" + name + "'][value='" + actor[key] + "']").prop({ checked:true });
                break;
            case "checkbox":
                $("#" + fieldTypes[key].id).prop("checked", actor[key]);
                break;

        }
    }
    actorState("old");
};
```

It's able to update thanks to the help from the posters below.

```
var updateActor = function() {
    $("#updateActor").unbind();

    // Assigning Form values to variables
    var firstN = $("#fName").val();
    var lastN = $("#lName").val();
    var gender = $("[name='gender']:checked").val();
    var birthdate = $("#birthDate").val();
    var action = $("#action").prop('checked');
    var comedy = $("#comedy").prop('checked');
    var drama = $("#drama").prop('checked');
    var sciencefiction = $("#sciencefiction").prop('checked');
    var horror =$("#horror").prop('checked');
    var suspense = $("#suspense").prop('checked');

    // creates updateActor variable that contains an object for each input value
    var updateActor = {fName: firstN, lName: lastN, gender: gender, birthDate: birthdate, action: action, comedy: comedy, drama: drama, suspense: suspense, sciencefiction: sciencefiction, horror: horror}

    var rowId = $("#updateActor").attr("rowid");

    // Creates a table of links for each added actor  with an id based from # of actors
    $("#actorsTable").find("a[data-idx='"+rowId+"']").replaceWith("<a href='' onclick='deleteActor(this)' class='update' data-idx='" + rowId + "'>" + updateActor.fName + " " + updateActor.lName + "</a>");

    actors.push(updateActor);
    actorState ("new");

};
```

[Example in action](http://codepen.io/zzzian/pen/oxmzOE?editors=0010)

Comment: Do you want to update that data back to table row again..right?

Comment: @Sid yeah when I click update, I'm trying to have the data back in the row it came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make few changes in your script and there you go.

1) When you are selecting your record by clicking on table row, apply that respective data-idx value to the "updateActor" button by adding some attribute to it(i.e rowid).

Add following code line after "var actor = actors[idx];" to do the same in your "selectActor" function

```
$("#updateActor").attr("rowid",idx);
```

2) Change your code in "updateActor" function as below:

2.1) Replace

```
var firstN = $("#fName"[row]).val();
```

with

```
var firstN = $("#fName").val();
```

2.2) Add following line of code after creating "updateActor" variable that contains an object for each input value (i.e. var updateActor = {fName: firstN, lName: lastN, ...)

```
var rowId = $("#updateActor").attr("rowid");
```

2.3) Replace

```
$("#actorsTable").append("<tr><td><a href='' onclick='deleteActor(this)' class='update' data-idx='" + actors.length + "'>" + newActor.fName + " " + newActor.lName + "</a></td></tr> ");
```

with

```
$("#actorsTable").find("a[data-idx='"+rowId+"']").replaceWith("<a href='' onclick='deleteActor(this)' class='update' data-idx='" + rowId + "'>" + updateActor.fName + " " + updateActor.lName + "</a>");
```

Comment: After messing around with it, it seems that I can update a row. But when I click on the updated row again it deletes the whole table. Or if I go click on a row that I haven't updated the update button doesn't work. I tried putting `unbind()` inside, right under `$("#updateActor").on("click", function () {});` The problems still persist.

http://codepen.io/zzzian/pen/oxmzOE?editors=0010

Comment: Could you explain why you're using data-idx instead of an id?

Comment: according to your code, your data-idx is indicating current row which is going to be updated or deleted

Comment: WRT to your first comment, it seems that while clicking on any row from table, before calling "selectActor" function, it is calling "updateActor" & "deleteActor". (ie in your html table row, there is a function call on "onClick"). According to requirement, it should only call selectActor first and then updateActor should be call at the time of saving. Also it seems that page is redirecting somehow when we are trying to update any row again.

Answer (score 0):

4 errors in the script above

1) newActor in the line below in the update statment should be changed to updateActor

```
$("#actorsTable").append("<tr><td><a href='' onclick='deleteActor(this)' class='update' data-idx='" + actors.length + "'>" + updateActor.fName + " " + updateActor.lName + "</a></td></tr> ");
```

2)

```
var firstN = $("#fName"[row]).val();
```

need to be

```
var firstN = $("#fName").val();
```

3) you need to update "actors[row]" in  the update function 
4) you need to remove the update row (old data) from the table as you're adding a new one at the end of the function.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. That was an error on my part with the `var firstN...[row]` I was trying that out early on, and mistakenly forgot to change it back when posting here.